# Hive combining full outer join and not in?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive query which looks like this

```
SELECT 
    a.uid, 
    a.order_id
FROM table_a a
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        uid, 
        order_id
    FROM table_b
) b
ON (a.uid = b.uid AND a.order_id = b.order_id)
```

This query results in a set of uids and order_ids.

Now, I have a `black_listed` table which has a set of uids. I want to have this set of black listed uids not to be part of the final result.

Is there a way I can add this remove-blacklisted-uids subquery to the above query (do this in a single query)

So if I have a table called `black_list` with `uid1` and `uid2`, both these uids should not be part of my final result of the first query.

Comment: are uid1 and uid2 separate columns in the black_list table?

Comment: No, values of the same column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a `left join`.

```
SELECT 
    a.uid, 
    a.order_id
FROM table_a a
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        uid, 
        order_id
    FROM table_b
) b
ON (a.uid = b.uid AND a.order_id = b.order_id)
LEFT JOIN black_listed bl on bl.id = a.uid 
WHERE bl.id IS NULL
```